# Value added to array is NULL?

Tags: java, arrays

In my code below, I am experiencing a problem I am unable to get around... when I add a class Person object to an array, it appears to add fine, however when I attempt to print out that object value form a specified array position, it outputs "null."

Here is the code

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.lang.String;

public class Main
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        int ARRAY_LENGTH = 2;

        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        Person[] Persons;

        Persons = new Person[ARRAY_LENGTH];

        for (int i = 0; i < ARRAY_LENGTH; i++)
        {
            System.out.println("Enter a name to add to the array: ");
            Persons[i] = new Person(in.next());
            System.out.println(Persons[i]);
        }

        Arrays.sort(Persons);

        for (int i = 0; i < ARRAY_LENGTH; i++)
        {
            System.out.println(Persons[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

&

```
public class Person implements Comparable<Person>
{
    private String name;

    public Person (String aName)
    {
        String name = aName;
    }

    public String getName()
    {
        return name;
    }

    public int compareTo(Person o)
    {
        Person other = (Person) o;
        if (this.name.equals(o.name))
        {
            return 0;
        }
        if (this.name.compareTo(o.name) < 0)
        {
            return -1;
        }
        return 1;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString()
    {
        return name;
    }
}
```

Comment: Your `Person` constructor doesn't assign a value to the field `name` - it declares a *local* variable called `name`. That's the problem. You should also consider just making your `compareTo` method return `name.compareTo(o.name);` - it's a much simpler approach.

Answer (score 3):

No, it hasn't added `null` to the array. It's put a reference to a `Person` object in the array, and when you call `toString()` on that `Person` object, it's returning the value of the `name` field... which is always `null`, because of this constructor:

```
public Person (String aName)
{
    String name = aName;
}
```

That isn't assigning a value to the `name` field - it's declaring a local variable called `name`. (I'd expect a decent IDE to issue a warning about that.)

You want:

```
public Person (String aName)
{
    name = aName;
}
```

Comment: That change (removing the 'String' declaration prior to the name = aName did the trick.  Also, I am using BlueJ as my IDE.  What IDE would you recommend I invest time in learning for Java?

Answer (score 2):

The constructor

```
public Person (String aName)
{
    String name = aName;
}
```

stores the name in a local variable.

Change this to

```
public Person (String aName)
{
    this.name = aName;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The constructor is wrong

```
public Person (String aName)
{
    String name = aName;
}
```

it is creating a new variable instead of assigning the field properly.

Try removing the type declaration:

```
public Person (String aName)
{
    name = aName;
}
```